# What is the correct solution of ReactJS Useeffect missing dependency issues on component did mount?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, react-hooks, use-effect

everyone

while I am working on React Function Component, I got the same problem everyday. **it is useeffect dependency problem.**

my working flow like the following to get the data by calling the RestAPI

- define useeffect with empty array [] for component did mount event. I want run the calling api one time
- add API calling function inside useeffect

my working code like the following.

```
const DevicesMain = () => {
  console.log("Devices Main render")
  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, initialState)
  const [sites, rooms, devices] = useSelector((state) => [state.sites, state.rooms, state.devices])
  const reduxDispatch = useDispatch()

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("did mount")

    if (!sites.get) {
      reduxDispatch(siteActions.getALL())
    }

    if (!rooms.get) {
      reduxDispatch(roomActions.getALL())
    }

    reduxDispatch(deviceActions.getALLWithIncludeCount())

    return () => {
      console.log("will unmount")

      if (subscription) {
        subscription.unsubscribe()
      }
    }
  }, [])

  return (
    <>
        ...
    </>
  )
}
```

after that, always I got the dependency missing Waring like the following.

```
React Hook useEffect has missing dependencies: 'reduxDispatch', 'rooms.get', 'sites.get', and 'subscription'. Either include them or remove the dependency array  react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
```

exactly the above warning makes my headache. for some days, I tried to remove this warning.

**at first**, **I added the dependencides that the warning message mentioned to me like the following.**

```
}, [reduxDispatch, rooms.get, sites.get, subscription])
```

after adding like the above, useeffect function is running over 1 time, as that function has rooms.get and sites.get as its dependency.

[image]

as you see my the above image, there are serveral **did mount** log.

**secondly, I disabled eslint like the following**

```
// eslint-disable-next-line
}, [])
```

exactly, I think that this is very basic problem. but still I didn't find what is the best solution for useeffect one time run.

if you give me the best solution, I am thanksful

Regards

Comment: Similar questions: [React get state from Redux store within useEffect](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58159108/6367213), [What is the best way to use redux action in useEffect?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60517307/6367213).

Answer (score 1):

Your'e doing perfectly fine. It's a suggestion related to es-lint and not particularly react it self. disabling eslint in this case is perfectly fine and the right approach infact.

Explanation: Eslint basically makes you aware to add dependencies as arguments in array which you are using and which might change in future. As a critical human, your job is to note whether you'd want that behaviour. In this scenario  you definitely don't want the behaviour so disabling eslint is the right and recommended way.

Note: Apart from this I would suggest to not listen for subscription on unmount because first of all you haven't defined a subscription variable and secondly there are no subscriptions(listnings) that your'e using in useEffect hook so no need for it.