# Redux dispatch in useEffect causing infinite rerender

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-hooks, use-effect

I have tried searching previous similar questions but many of the answers suggest passing in a dependency array to `useEffect`, which I already have done.

This is basically a user's show page:

```
const Profile = ({ currentUser, profileOwner, getProfileInfo, isMine }) => {
  useEffect(() => {
    getProfileInfo();
  }, [profileOwner]);

  return (stuff)
}
```

This is its container:

```
const mapStateToProps = ({ session, users }, ownProps) => ({
  currentUser: users[session.id],
  profileOwner: users[ownProps.params.userId],
  isMine: session.id === parseInt(ownProps.params.userId),
});

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch, ownProps) => ({
  getProfileInfo: () => dispatch(getProfileInfo(ownProps.params.userId)),
});
```

And this is the action that I assume is somehow causing the re-render:

```
export const getProfileInfo = (userId) => (dispatch) =>
  axios.get(`/api/users/${userId}`).then((res) => res.data)
    .then((user) => dispatch(receiveProfileOwner(user)));
```

If I take `profileOwner` out of the dependency array, there is no more infinite loop, but then it won't fetch the user data if I navigate to a different user's profile.
As far as I can see, the value of `profileOwner` shouldn't be changing at all after it was fetched the first time, so it is still a puzzle to me why I have this problem.

Comment: Have you checked this out? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60517307/what-is-the-best-way-to-use-redux-action-in-useeffect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like using `profileOwner` as the dependency was the mistake. The component already receives the routing params as props, so I changed the useEffect to this:

```
const Profile = ({ currentUser, profileOwner, getProfileInfo, isMine, params: { userId } }) => {
  useEffect(() => {
    getProfileInfo();
  }, [userId]);
```

It's kind of messy, and I expect that there is a better way to do this than adding more props, but it does solve the problem.